# how to multiple login in one application like admin and employee in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have two protected areas in one application but only the admin user can login in both areas user (Admin) and employee. Please give me a suggestion to my question.

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('employee/login', array(
  'uses' => 'LoginController@create',
  'as' => 'login.create'
));

Route::post('employee/login', array(
  'uses' => 'LoginController@store',
  'as' => 'login.store'
));
```

**LoginController.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use View;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Input;
use Auth;
use Config;
use Redirect;
use App\Employee;
use DB;
use Validator;

class LoginController extends Controller {

     public function __construct()
     {
        Config::set('auth.model', 'Employee');
        Config::set('session.path', '/employee');
     }

     public function create()
     {
        return View::make('employee.login');
     }

     public function store()
     {
        if(Auth::attempt(array('email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password'))))
        {
            return Redirect::intended('employee/home');
        }

        return Redirect::route('login.create')
            ->withInput()
            ->with('login_errors', true);
    }

    public function destroy()
    {
        Log::logout();

        return View::make('employee.destroy');
    }
}
```

**Login.blade.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href='css/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='../css/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="head_text">
            <h2 style="text-align:center;">Employee Login</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="login_table">   
         {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'login.store')) !!}
            <h1 style="text-align:center;">Login</h1>

            <p>
                {!! $errors->first('email') !!}
                {!! $errors->first('password') !!}
            </p>

            <p>
                {!! Form::label('email', 'Email Address') !!}
                {!! Form::text('email', Input::old('email'), array('placeholder' => 'awesome@awesome.com')) !!}
            </p>

            <p>
                {!! Form::label('password', 'Password') !!}
                {!! Form::password('password') !!}
            </p>

            <p>
                {!! Form::submit('Login') !!}
            </p>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Employee(model)

```
<?php namespace App\Models;;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; 
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable; 
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword; 
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword; 
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticable; 
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticable as AuthenticableTrait; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; 
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class Employee extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    protected $table = 'employee';

    protected $fillable = [
        'firstname',
        'lastname',
        'email',
        'birthdate',
        'address',
        'phone',
        'mobileno',
        'employeetype',
        'partment',
        'uniqueemployeeid',
        'password',
        'repassword'
    ];

    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }

    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        return 'remember_token';
    }

    public function setPasswordAttrribute($password)
    {
        $this->attributes['password']=Hash::make($password);    
    }
    public static $rules = array(
        'firstname'           => 'required',
        'lastname'            => 'required',                      
        'email'               => 'required|email', 
        'birthdate'           => 'required',  
        'address'             => 'required',
        'phone'               => 'required',
        'mobileno'            => 'required',
        'employeetype'        => 'required',
        'department'          => 'required',
        'uniqueemployeeid'    => 'required',
        'password'            => 'required',
        'repassword'          => 'required|same:password'
    );
    public function getFullName()
    {
        return $this->firstname ;
    }

}
```

auth.php

```
<?php

return [

    'driver' => 'eloquent',

    'model' => 'App\User',
    'model' => 'App\Employee',

    'table' => 'users',
    'table' => 'employee',

    'password' => [
        'email' => 'emails.password',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],

];
```

Comment: Are you using Laravel 4 or Laravel 5?

Comment: I'm unable to give a full answer at the moment but I hope this comment helps. Start with a fresh install of laravel and add a `role` attribute to the `users` migration. You can then check if a user has a certain role before hitting a route by using a middleware and middleware parameters: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware#middleware-parameters. You can protect routes using route groups: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-groups You DO NOT want to be making two seperate tables for different user types - use one and give them a role! HTH

Comment: You can do as @haakym says or you can use a package designed for that, such as https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust

Comment: Thanks for help but i fetch and enter employee data to the employee table like email,password,name,etc.

Answer (score 3):

To achieve that, you have to go with one of two approaches: RBAC or Multi authentication.

#### Role-based access control

If your user data (email, password, name,..) are stored in one table, go with RBAC. RBAC works by assigning roles to every user, so you will have user with admin or employee role. Then using middlewares, you can restrict access to your protected areas based on the roles of the authenticated user. There's multiple well documented Laravel packages that you could use to achieve that like [Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) or [Laravel-permissions](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission)

#### Multi Authentication

If the user data isn't stored in one table, for example you have admin table and employee table. Use multi authentication, where you can define multiple authenticatable models or user tables. Then you can restrict access to the protected area based on the authenticated user itself. This's a built-in feature in Laravel 5.2. For Laravel 5.1, you could use the [MultiAuth](https://github.com/Kbwebs/MultiAuth) package.